# DNS Response Packets

Tags: dns

I'm trying to code my own DNS server, I'm reading through RFC1035 on DNS but I have a few queries:

1) I want my server to respond with a CNAME for a particular request, but no A records - can I do this? for example, receive request for 'server1.com', response 'CNAME server2.com', and then the client queries another DNS server to get the A record for 'server2.com'.
I've currently set the header to: '\x84\x00' such to say this is the authoritive server, but recurse is not possible. Is this right?

2) I want my server to respond with no records for any other request, such that the client then queries a different DNS server for the records. I've currently set header to '\x83\x03' such to signal a NAME ERROR reply code. Is this right? Then what do I follow this with, zeros in all the other fields, or just end the packet there? I don't want to respond with 'this name doesn't exist', rather 'I don't know this name, try someone else' - how do I do this?

Many Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Sounds about right - in fact, CNAME *with* A records is incorrect ([RFC1034 section 3.6.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034#section-3.6.2): "If a CNAME RR is present at a node, no other data should be present").
2. This would be very unusual behaviour from an authoritative nameserver - I'd suggest rethinking it or at least testing with some real-life resolvers to ensure they do what you want. RCODE #3 ("name error" or NXDOMAIN) is positive confirmation that the name **doesn't exist**. This would cause resolvers to terminate resolution and possibly cache the nonexistence of the name, which doesn't sound like what you're after. If you want the resolver to query one of the other nameservers that was delegated to for that zone, I guess SERVFAIL (RCODE #2) is the most appropriate/likely to have the desired effect.

By the way, for debugging the exact format of your DNS packets I can highly recommend [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) for its decoding accuracy compared with pasting hex codes into Stack Overflow ;)

Comment: Thanks Simon - The reason I asked about CNAME with A records is that looking at wireshark captures, the single response from the DNS server has multiple records, a CNAME and then the attached A records. But if returning just a CNAME is valid then that's fine. And yeah I'll try RCODE #2 and look at some more packet captures :) Thanks!

Comment: Actually, CNAME without A records doesn't seem to work. I can NSLOOKUP and retrieve the CNAME record fine, but if I try to ping it still hasn't got an A record so responses 'unknown host' - any ideas?

Comment: Are you using `nslookup` to query the authoritative nameserver directly, or via a recursive nameserver?

Comment: directly, maybe that's what I'm doing wrong :) So if i'm hosting my custon dns on server1.com, I set server1's ns records to my servers ip, so when an external client queries their dns, it retreives the CNAME from server1.com and then resolves it on their dns?

Comment: Correct - once their nameserver retrieves the CNAME, it performs a new query for `server2.com`, then appends the results to the final response along with the intermediate CNAME - so the client receives a packet containing both records.

Answer (score 1):

In the CNAME case, your (authoritative) server should just return the CNAME in the answer section *unless* it is also authoritative for the domain that the CNAME points to, in which case it should also include the result of following the CNAME.

For your second case you should return RCODE 5 ("REFUSED") - this is the preferred error that an authoritative server should give when asked a question for a domain for which it is not configured.

Following that, you still need to send the four 16-bit count fields and a copy of the question from the original request.  In this case the four counts would be (1, 0, 0, 0) - one question, no answer, no ns records, no additional records.